# How to make a control resizable in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wpf-controls

I want the user to resize a few combined controls and a few single controls in Silverlight during runtime. How can I manage this? Is there a way to put the controls in rectangles and make the rectangles resizable in some way? I often see textboxes and controls with a resize area in the lower right corner just like the textboxes on this site. How can I make these in Silverlight?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I put my control(s) into grids and let the GridSplitter resize the grids.

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look at this](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/20614.aspx)

Unfortunately Silverlight has no Adorner support (yet?)

Answer (score 0):

This gentlemen has a really good answer and a demo for the exact problem:
http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/03/14/a-silverlight-resizable-textblock-and-other-resizable-things.html